# Append javascript dictionary to other dictionary

Tags: javascript, python, json, autocomplete, materialize

I am creating an app with materialize css. Materialize css has an autocomplete js feature. You can pass in data to autocomplete. I also have a python flask backend that returns a python dictionary in JSON form. Javascript receives it on the front end and parses the JSON data. I was wondering if it would be possible to append the JSON data into the premade autocomplete. Here is my code:

```
<script>
  //parse json data
  var datas = JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson | safe}}');
  console.log(datas)
  console.log(datas['Nick'])

    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
          data: {
            'Apple': null,
            datas: null
          }
        });
    </script>
```

My console looks like this, so I know I have a useable python dictionary:

```
{Nick: "null", User: "null"}
    Nick: "null"
    User: "null"
    __proto__: Object
null
```

I have tried using my data directly, passing it in through the data field instead of data: but I have no luck.
I would like to use my JSON data in the data field of the autocomplete, how would I do this? Thank you!

Comment: which autocomplete library you are using?

and do you want to add JSON data on page load only?

Comment: @Rajan I am using materialize css autocomplete - In my flask app, I pass in my JSON data and convert it to a javascript dict on the page load.

Comment: and you want to append `{'Apple': null}` and `datas` at page load only right?

Comment: @Rajan basically I want to have my JSON list appear in the autocomplete data at page load only.

Comment: Let me know if the solution works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append your objects you can do, something like:

```
<script>
  var datas = JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson | safe}}');
  var newData = $.extend({'Apple':null}, datas);

  $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: newData
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!